# Triviality, ampleness, nefness, and bigness of the tangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cotangent-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective connected variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $T_X$ be its tangent bundle.

If $T_X$ is ample, then $X$ is isomorphic to a projective space by Mori's theorem.

If $T_X$ is trivial, then $X$ is isomorphic to an abelian variety.

If $T_X$ is nef, then the Albanese map $X\to A_X$ is smooth, and the fibres are Fano varieties with nef tangent bundle by work of Demailly-Peternell-Schneider. Conjecturally, these Fano fibres are even rational homogeneous spaces.

I wonder whether there are other questions one might ask.

> > For example, what if $T_X$ is big? What do we expect then?

> > What if $T_X$ is $m$-ample for some integer $m\geq 1$?

> > What about $\Lambda^pT_X$ being trivial (resp. ample) for some $p=1,\ldots, \dim X$. (In the ample case, this interpolates between between projective space where $p=1$   and Fano varieties where $p=\dim X$.)

> > Are there any other properties of $T_X$ which force (even just conjecturally) properties of $X$?

Comment: Are all of these properties defined as the line bundle $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P T_X}(1)$ having that property, as with ampleness?

Comment: @TabesBridges Yes, although there are indeed other ways of defining bigness, due to Viehweg I believe.

Comment: You may add a weak version of ampleness like m-ample, take m=1, see https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://archive.ymsc.tsinghua.edu.cn/pacm_download/49/1066-MathAnn2016.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjRx9uC6e3rAhWITBUIHZmgA5Q4ChAWMAl6BAgDEAE&usg=AOvVaw1TpcEdvVrt4hpmu1YTyDD_

Comment: But when $K_X$ is1-ample then finding a type of canonical metrics like Kähler-Einstein metric is related to new conditions.

Comment: On bigness: recent work of https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09476 has completely settled the bigness of $T_X$ for del Pezzo surfaces (also considered in https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11010, if it's not poor form to refer to one's own papers)- basically, hard to know what bigness of $T_X$ means, as del Pezzos of degrees 5 or more have big tangent bundle and those of degrees 4 or less do not- I don't know why this should be true more systematically, but maybe someone does!

Comment: I'll add also that Campana--Peternell considered the question of nefness of $\bigwedge^2 T_X$ on Fano threefolds (see http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1992__83_3_329_0/); it would be interesting to know what happens in higher dimension.